# Logistic regression, deducing parameters from probability

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I ran a logistic regression and know how to deduce the probability of success from select parameters:

```
predict(glm , data , type = "response")
```

However, how do we go the other way around? Let's say my data is composed of :

- survival (binary) (outcome)
- age (continuous) (parameter)
- sex (binary) (parameter)

I would like to know, based on some probability $\alpha$ of survival, how old is the person, if boy or girl.

Here is a picture of probability graph
[image]

Comment: You can't know that for sure, there is going to be many solutions.  You can derive an expression for the many solutions using standard linear algebra techniques though, by inverting the link function and solving the resulting linear equation.

Comment: @MatthewDrury , I added the graph I obtained, I have the impression that we should be able to go from proba to age.

Comment: But from that graph you get *many* solutions, one for each combination of the other variables ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Yes, so graphically, if we are to take 50% proba, as sex 0 youd be some 42 years old, and as sex 1 you would be 22